# Another steam launching problem in ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, steam

After I installed the steam via Software Center, it won't start at all, just flashed and closed itself. My video driver is Nvidia.

```
tom@tom-desktop:~/Downloads$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 13.10 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8328 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_72FCB912524C8721AE2A110432921374
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8328 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_72FCB912524C8721AE2A110432921374
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8328 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 8328 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[1222/192029:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1386799584_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20131222192028_1.dmp
/home/tom/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  8491 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-ef1194b1-cded-4ffc-8257-d2ebf2131222
```

Comment: bug reports are off topic on Ask Ubuntu. Report the bug and hope it gets resolved. You can use the Windows version of wine via steam, but it will be buggy too. But you can try it. Also why are you running 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I ended up having to install it directly from the Steam website and then complete installation by running it from the terminal.

I hope you got this figured out by now since it's been so long, but just in case you haven't here's what I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
sudo apt-get clear
```

Then I removed the file by clicking on the `Files` icon on the left of the screen and once in there make hidden files visible by clicking on `View` at the top of the screen and selecting that option. Then you'll be able to see the Steam folder to delete it.

After it's fully removed, go to the Steam website and install the file. When it's finished downloading you can try to click the icon. It most likely won't run, but you can go into terminal to run it like this:

```
cd .steam/steam
sudo ./ steam.sh
```

Then it should completely install and work.